# Spring boot war running on tomcat with port number specified in properties file

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I want to deploy Spring boot app as a war in tomcat server. And my tomcat port is 8088. But I want to start my app on port number specified in `application.yml` file. Is it possible?

Like if I have declared port in yml file:

```
server:
    port: 8090
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. Your tomcat port is decided by the web server configuration (server.xml) and all the wars deployed will be served on that port.

Comment: Yes, the port you specify there is for your local Tomcat instance.